# Column to show the status of the rows added to cart Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on cart application where users apply filters and submit subsequently rows will be displayed in the table. when user selects a row/rows clicks on button addToCart for each row I get the response from back-end as true
( if added successfully), false ( if already in the cart).

Using Angular js 1.3 working on Salesforce platform - Visual force page.

Javascript:

```
'{!$RemoteAction.APTS_CustomSolutionctrl.addToCart}', value.APTS_Product__c, value.Id, cartID, 0, null,
                                    function(result, event) {
                                        if(result == true){
                                            $scope.itemStatus = result;
                                            $scope.isAdded = true;
                                            $scope.$apply();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                        $scope.itemStatus = result;
                                        $scope.isAdded = false;
                                         $scope.$apply();
                                        }
                                        console.log(result);
                                    });
```

HTML:

```
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="selectedProductItem.Product_Level_5__c != 'FL PROFILES'">{{removeAmparsendFilter(fldc.APTS_Attribute_Value3__r.Name)}}</td>
                            <td ng-if="selectedProductItem.Product_Level_5__c == 'FL PROFILES'">{{removeAmparsendFilter(fldc.APTS_Attribute_Value2__r.Name)}}</td>
                            <td ng-if="productItems[1].APTS_Display_Order__c == 2">{{fldc.APTS_Attribute_Value1__r.Name}}</td>                                
                            <td ng-if="selectedProductItem.APTS_Inventory_Applicable__c && selectedProductItem.Product_Level_5__c != 'FL PROFILES'" >{{fldc.APTS_Inventory_Available__c}}</td>
                            <td>{{fldc.APTS_Price__c.toFixed(2)}}</td>
                            <td ng-if="isAdded"><span ng-if="fldc.selected == true">{{itemStatus}}</span></td>
                        </tr>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr4Zn.png)

Comment: sorry, i was unable to understand your problem. What do you really need?

Comment: Hi @leo_ap can you share your email id, I can send you the code for better understanding.

Comment: Also see the Image I have attached at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Ramesh You should post the code in your question. The point of this site is solve problems with the idea that future users can use the solution when they encounter similar problems. By sending the code via email, you are removing this aspect and essentially using this as a freelance site for help.

Comment: Hello @Ramesh, sorry, I don't know what is the id of my email, it may be the very email address, but since I don't know the database structure of my email provider, I can't guarantee that. Also, I don't think that it would be honest with the stack overflow community, we must enforce the practice to make the discussions public

Comment: Totally agreed. I am afraid to post the entire code here for some other reasons.

Comment: Hi @Ramesh You just share a fiddle with your code. That will help us  to solve your problem quickly. Thanks

Comment: Can you please describe actually what is the issue? What will be output of your code? That will help us to fix that.